# Is Stack Overflow tag-wiki also open?

Tags: support, tags, tag-wiki, licensing, tag-excerpt

I am developing a tagging system and wanted to seed the tags list from Stack Overflow. Thank you Stack Exchange for opening up this data to the public: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1069131/get-all-tags

Can I **also** use the "Usage guidance" text for each of the tags? The data is available here:
https://stackoverflow.com/tags

If you click a tag for the details and then click "improve tag info" there is a tag-wiki entry: https://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/3

What I would like to use is the "Usage guidance (excerpt)" text from the wiki.

How can I find out if this is covered in a license somewhere?

If they did not include that information in their Data Explorer I assume this information belongs to Stack Exchange, but I want to check.

Comment: Related request on MSE: [Show license info for tag excerpts and wikis explicitly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382862/335251)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Firstly, in regards to the licences, from the bottom of **every page** on the site at the bottom right:

> user contributions licensed under [CC BY-SA](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing).

Content in Wiki/Excerpts are user contributions and so are licenced under the CC BY-SA licences. I will admit, however, that the tag's info page themselves (such as [sql's](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info)) don't *appear to display* the licence terms the content is under (*which has been under [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) since [May 2020](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/347794/241919), [thanks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420826/is-stackoverflow-tag-wiki-open-also/420829?noredirect=1#comment929895_420829) [Andrew T.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2821954/andrew-t)*), but the above quote does explicitly cover the content (due to them being user contributions).

This can actually be verified in the Data Explorer, where you are incorrectly under the assumption that the Wiki and Excerpt data isn't stored; it is in `Posts` table with Tag Wiki and Tag Excerpts having a `PostTypeID` of `5` and `4` respectively.

The `Posts` table also contains the licence the content is under in the `ContentLicense` column. As things *have* changed over the years, then if you *do* want to take all the information you will need to ensure that you adhere to the appropriate licence for that wiki/excerpt. Note, as well, that a tag's wiki and excerpt can be under **different** versions of CC BY-SA. Using [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) as an example again, note that the Wiki is licenced under CC BY-SA 4.0 but the Excerpt is under CC BY-SA 3.0.

The query you could use to get the information is as follows:

```sql
SELECT T.TagName,
       T.[Count],
       W.Body AS Wiki,
       W.ContentLicense AS WikiLicence,
       E.Body AS Excerpt,
       E.ContentLicense AS ExcerptLicence
FROM dbo.Tags T
     LEFT JOIN dbo.Posts W ON T.WikiPostId = W.Id
                          AND W.PostTypeId = 5
     LEFT JOIN dbo.Posts E ON T.ExcerptPostId = E.Id
                          AND E.PostTypeId = 4
--Where [Count]>10
ORDER BY Count DESC;
```

Which I've also put into [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1655417).

Comment: Is anyone aware of a post asking if it's by design that the licence that the excerpt/wiki is under isn't displayed on the tag's info page? I had a bit of a search, but my Google-Fu is failing me. If not, then I'll likely create a [[meta-tag:feature-request]]; if event comments have the licence available (via a tool tip) on the page, it make little sence that the tag's info doesn't.

Comment: [status-review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/347794/241919) since 2020.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewT. . I *assumed* it would be *somewhere*.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent, to the point, exhaustive explanation and even including an appropriate query!

Comment: Created a feature request: [Show license info for tag excerpts and wikis explicitly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382862/241919)

Answer (score 6):

On every page of SO, at the very bottom left, there is the license:

> Site design / logo © 2022 Stack Exchange Inc; user contributions licensed under [CC BY-SA](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing).

You are **allowed** to use the data, but make sure to adhere to the rules and agreements of the license.